# Check for the existence of empty parameters in CGI.pm

Tags: perl, cgi

To check if a request parameter has a value (http://example.com?my_param=value) you can use

```
query->param('my_param')
```

This seems to be flaky if the no_value form is used: http://example.com?my_param .

Is there a way to check simply the existence of parameters in CGI.pm ?

Comment: Please read the following [article](https://www.perl.com/article/perl-and-cgi/) and decide for yourself if you should use CGI module.

Comment: For a more humorous take on the same topic, see [this talk by Perl's release manager Sawyer X](https://youtu.be/jKOqtRMT85s).

Comment: @PolarBear: can you replace this for an existing codebase ?

Comment: @serv-inc I could do it - if you are willing to pay me it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the parameter is present with defined. the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header;

my $defined = defined $cgi->param('tt');
my $val = $cgi->param('tt');
print <<END;
<!doctype html>
<html> HTML Goes Here 
<h1>tt: "$defined" "$val"</h1>
</html>
END
```

Will generate the output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html> HTML Goes Here 
<h1>tt: "1" ""</h1>
</html>
```

when the URI is http:///cgi-bin/t.pl?someother=something&tt

Unfortunately this doesn't work when it is the **only** parameter.

So to be sure, you have to test:

```
my $defined = defined $cgi->param('tt') || $ENV{QUERY_STRING} eq 'tt';
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to depend on the browser implementation. According to [this Perlmonks thread from 2001](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=84974), empty parameters might not be returned. But if they are, the key will be there, but contain an empty string `q{}`. If the argument wasn't present, it will be `undef`, so you can check with [`defined`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html).

Comment: This did not work : `defined query->param('my_param');` ist not true if the param exists (cgi.pm 4.44) . Still thanks

Comment: This doesn't work when it is the only parameter. Don't know if this is a bug or not.

Comment: @GeorgMavridis you mean `http://example.org/foo?bar` where there is just one param but no value and no equals?

Comment: Yes, there it doesn't. But in `http://example.org/foo?bar&baz` it does work.